# automating data entry in a web form using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to input data into excel and then populate it into a website.
I keep getting an error message saying: "automation error, the interface is unknown".
Is it anything to do with the settings on IE or excel?

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://charterweb.santanderuk.gs.corp/CharterServiceChain/default.aspx"  

    'Wait for loding
    Do While .Busy
    Loop

    Do While .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

End With

Set cmcRef = ie.document.getElementById("M_E_ctlPartField214_V")
cmcRef.Value = "test"

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is giving the error?, Just note that there was a "spelling" error at this line: `Set cmcRef = ie.document.getElementById("M_E_ctlPartField214_V")`

Comment: on the do  while... now there is an error saying, the interference is unknown...

Comment: Write 'Do events' on the line before the first 'Loop'.

Comment: The resource is not found when I look for it. Can you view it in a browser?

Comment: what do you mean?